# Connecting to a service running directly on a GitHub Actions Runner

Tags: github, networking, containers, github-actions

I want to create a GitHub Actions workflow to automatically test web based software. I need to manually log in with my local web browser for verification. How do I map the runner's public IP and expose the correct ports (let's say 3000), so that I can connect directly to the service from my local machine and verify some functions in the browser?

Here is a conceptually related workflow that is similar enough to my situation:

```
name: Start NPM Server

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  start-server:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Check IP
      run: curl https://api.ipify.org
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm install
    - name: Start server
      run: |
        npm start
        sleep 10000
```

I have found the external IP, but I haven't found a way to actually create the connection and access it from my web browser. Is it even feasible for me to open the port 3000, connect to the external ip that I find from the "Check IP" step, and do that verification manually?

Comment: AFAIK, something like that is not available. Regarding running your tests, you can simply write a test script using a headless browser to simulate this flow.

Comment: @Azeem, what do you think about the possibility of using a self hosted runner on the same machine, and connecting to it there directly?

I tried this out, but AFAIK there is no way of exposing a port in the runner to outside the containerized environment.

If not, using a headless browser test suite would be a great idea, thank you!